# How to handle push notification on iOS device with multiple logged in users?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I have an application, and now only one user can logged in, and got push notifications. I would like to allow in the application that more than one user can logged in the same time, and send to them push notifications.

My problem is that I dont know which user got the push notification, and i cant load the user specific view in my application. What is the best practice to handle this problem on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert the identifier of the user who recieved the notification in the custom payload of it (like described here [Can apple push notifications send more parameters than alert and sound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236630/can-apple-push-notifications-send-more-parameters-than-alert-and-sound)), so the app can know wich of the logged users is the reciever.